# Dividing a n- cochain by a 1-cochain

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Assume that $X$ is  a path connected hausdorff topological space. Let $\alpha\in C^{1}(X,\mathbb{R})$ and  $\beta\in C^{n}(X,\mathbb{R})$ be cochains in real singular cohomology. Asume that $\alpha \smile \beta=0$.

> Is there a $n-1$ cochain $\gamma$ with $\beta=\alpha \smile \gamma$ ?

This is motivated by the similar situation, with affirmative answer, in De Rham cohomology and differential forms. In fact this smooth version is used to define the Godbillon Vey invariant for  a codimension one foliation.

Comment: What if $\alpha=0$. In fact, it's completely unclear what the relation between the two conditions is as, in general,  $\alpha\smile\alpha\ne0$ for a $1$-**cochain** (or even cocycle) $\alpha$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev  befor this post I was thinking to singular cohomological version of "Non vanishing one form" in term of cochain. Is it  a  good  idea to define $\alpha$ vanish at a point $z\in X$ if for every curve passing $z$, the pull bach cochain is  vanishing at a point of interval?(with an appropriate definition, for the intervalcase). In fact My main motivation was the following: Let $\alpha$ be  a non vanishing 1-cochain on  compact n dimensional space $X$(not necessarilly manifold) with $\alpha \smile \sigma \alpha=0$. can we divid $X$ to disjoint union of n-1  dim subspace $L_{t}$....

Comment: such that the restriction of $\alpha$ to each $L_{t}$ is identically zero?

Comment: As Alex remarked, this question is rather less natural for singular cochains than it is for de Rham cochains; the condition that $\alpha\smile\beta=0$ is extremely strong for singular cochains.  For instance, suppose $\alpha$ is "nowhere vanishing" in the fairly weak sense that for every $x\in X$, there is some path $\gamma$ ending at $x$ such that $\alpha(\gamma)\neq 0$.  Then if $\alpha\smile\beta=0$, $\beta$ itself must be $0$!

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev according to your statment $\alpha \smile \alpha \neq 0$, what about if we consider the main question in cohomology classes? In cohomology $\alpha \smile \alpha=0$

Comment: @EricWofsey  is it  a  good singular versionof non vanishing property? $\alpha(\gamma) \neq 0$ for  a $\gamma$ ending at $x$?

Comment: The corresponding question in cohomology also has a negative answer.  If $X$ is the plane with $n$ points removed, then $H^*(X)$ is freely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ together with classes $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n$ satisfying $\alpha_i\alpha_j=0$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: note OP is taking coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland As I said to Alex Degtyarev, we need  to a non vanishing type condition for our 1-cochain. Without this, even in derham cohomology, we can not divid by 1-forms.